# git - forced update. What happened?

Tags: git, git-push

When I do `git push --force` I see next output from `git`:

```
$ git push --force
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 2.36 KiB | 1.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
To repo:/v1/repos/DB-Hooks
 + 7b4eaa2...1295174 reimplement -> reimplement (forced update)

$ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit 7b4eaa2...1295174
* 1295174 (HEAD -> reimplement) TEMPORARY
* 0f477bf Prettify code
* 09630ef Setup $DB::single
* 7b4eaa2 TEMPORARY
```

How can I check what happened here from this log?

1. Which commits are mine? (under "mine" I mean the changes done in my local repository, including amended commits)
2. Which commits are replaced and what replaced in those commits?
3. Which commits are gone from remote? (what changes I introduce in my local repository)

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Which commits are mine?

You need to define "mine".  What does it mean for a commit to be "yours"?

**Edit**: you added *under "mine" I mean the changes done in my local repository, including amended commits*.  First, always remember that commits are snapshots; to turn a snapshot into a change-set, you must pick some other commit and run `git diff` to compare the two commits.  The result of the comparison is a set of instructions for turning the first snapshot into the second snapshot.  That's not necessarily something you, or even anyone, did: it's just a set of changes that produce the *same result*.  (This is why sometimes `git diff` says "delete the close brace of a previous block, plus most of this block" rather than "delete all of this block".)

Git isn't really about *where* a commit was made: if you connect two Git repositories, any commit with hash ID `a1b2c3d`, for instance, in *either* repo is *the same commit* as a commit with hash ID `a1b2c3d` in the other repo.  What `git push` and `git fetch` do is connect two Git repositories, and transfer commits between them.  A push operation means *connect my repo to someone else's and attempt to give the someone-else some commits I have in my repo, which I assume they don't have yet.*  A fetch operation means *connect my repo to someone else's repo and attempt to get commits they have, that I assume I don't have yet.*

If you fetch from Alice's repository, then push to Bob's repository, this allows you to transfer commits that originally were only in Alice's repository, over to Bob's repository.  So the fact that you gave Bob commit `a1b2c3d` doesn't mean that commit `a1b2c3d` is something you wrote yourself, it just means Bob didn't have `a1b2c3d`—he had not yet obtained it directly from Alice, or from anyone else either.

Last, if you run `git commit --amend`, that doesn't *change* any existing commit.  Instead, it just makes a new (different, presumably better) commit whose *parent* is the same as the `--amend`ed commit's parent:

```
...--o--o--0bad   <-- branch
```

becomes:

```
          0bad   [abandoned]
         /
...--o--o--1337   <-- branch
```

if the old commit's hash begins with `0bad` and the new one's begins with `1337`.

> 2. Which commits are replaced ...

None.  Commits are identified by hash IDs.  Those hash IDs continue to identify the same commits.

However, we do know from the `git push` output that the name `reimplement` in the other Git used to represent the commit whose hash ID is `7b4eaa2`, and now represents the commit whose hash ID is `1295174`.  This factors into your question 3:

> 3. Which commits are gone from remote?

We also know two more things from your own `git log` output:

- The string `7b4eaa2...1295174` selects the four displayed commits.  Since `A...B` means "commits reachable from either `A` or `B` but not from both `A` and `B`", that means those four commits are reachable from one of those two commits, but not from both of them.
- The output from `git log --graph` is [further restrained to occur in topological order](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_ordering):

> > Show no parents before all of its children are shown, and avoid showing commits on multiple lines of history intermixed.

Since `7b4eaa2` came out last, this means all of its children have been shown before that point.  Since `1295174` came out first, it has no children.  The intermediate commits must either be children of `7b4eaa2` (i.e., `7b4eaa2` is their parent or grandparent), or parents of `1295174`.

#### Putting these all together

We know that `1295174` is the new tip of `reimplement` in the remote (since the push was accepted and it is the tip of `reimplement` in your own repository):

```
... <-1295174   <-- reimplement
```

We know that the remote's old `reimplement`, before the `git push`, ended with:

```
... <-7b4eaa2
```

What we must consider is whether we should draw what is now in your own repository like this:

```
?--09630ef--0f477bf--1295174   <-- reimplement
 \
  7b4eaa2   [abandoned]
```

or like this:

```
?--1295174   <-- reimplement
 \
  09630ef--0f477bf--7b4eaa2   [abandoned]
```

or even like this:

```
?--09630ef--1295174   <-- reimplement
 \
  0f477bf--7b4eaa2   [abandoned]
```

Your `git log 1295174...7b4eaa2` would show the first one as what we've seen.  It would show the second, though, as:

```
* 1295174 (HEAD -> reimplement) TEMPORARY
* 7b4eaa2 TEMPORARY
* 09630ef Setup $DB::single
* 0f477bf Prettify code
```

and the third in yet another form.  (If `1295174` were a merge commit with both `0f477bf` and `09630ef` as parents, we'd see yet a different graph output: we know for certain that all the commits shown here are linearly related or unrelated.)  Hence, going back to Q3:

> 3. Which commits are gone from remote?

we can say for certain that `7b4eaa2` is no longer reachable, in that Git, by the name `reimplement`.  The name `reimplement` instead names `1295174`, and the parent of `1295174` is `0f477bf` and the parent of `0f477bf` is `09630ef`.

If `7b4eaa2` is *completely* unreachable by branch or tag or similar names in the remote Git, *and* the remote Git has no reflogs, *and* a garbage collection pass has completed, commit `7b4eaa2` will have been collected and removed.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear and round some useful options (see my answer). But I still do not find option which will show changes in not `cherry-picked` commits (see suggested output in that answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> **To display last commit diff**

```
git diff HEAD~1
```

> **To display last commit modified files**

```
git diff HEAD~1 --name-only
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found these two options helpful to see what is comming on `--left-right --cherry-pick  --cherry-mark --boundary`:

> --left-right
>   Mark which side of a symmetric difference a commit is reachable from. Commits from the
>              left side are prefixed with < and those from the right with >

`--boudary` I need it to show parent root

> --cherry-pick
>      Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the “other side” when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --left-right --cherry-pick --boundary 8cb6531...1295174
> 1295174 (HEAD -> reimplement) TEMPORARY
> 0f477bf Prettify code
> 09630ef Setup $DB::single
> 1e1b4a3 Wrap whole DB::DB into &dbcall by moving DB::db into DB::interact
| < 8cb6531 TEMPORARY
| < e348241 Wrap whole DB::DB into &dbcall by moving DB::db into DB::interact
|/  
o 6086d62 Code comment
```

Or with `--cherry-mark` we can see not touched commits:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --left-right --cherry-mark --boundary 8cb6531...1295174
> 1295174 (HEAD -> reimplement) TEMPORARY
> 0f477bf Prettify code
> 09630ef Setup $DB::single
= 3e4cc19 Debugger debugging is finished. Remove mark
= 3df5e8c Fix doc
> 1e1b4a3 Wrap whole DB::DB into &dbcall by moving DB::db into DB::interact
| < 8cb6531 TEMPORARY
| = 5b1ce15 Debugger debugging is finished. Remove mark
| = 8588e00 Fix doc
| < e348241 Wrap whole DB::DB into &dbcall by moving DB::db into DB::interact
|/  
o 6086d62 Code comment
```

Here we can understand that:

1. commits `3e4cc19` and `3df5e8c` are not touched and same as `5b1ce15`, `8588e00` correspondingly
2. commits marked by `>` sign were added in your local repository
3. commits marked by `<` sign were removed from remote repository

Because the commit `Wrap whole DB::DB into &dbcall by moving DB::db into DB::interact` has same name on local and remote repos we can suppose that the `e348241` commit was changed and amended. And can see what was changed there:

```
$ git diff e348241 1e1b4a3
diff --git a/lib/DB/Commands.pm b/lib/DB/Commands.pm
index cb5b237..4f664fa 100644
--- a/lib/DB/Commands.pm
+++ b/lib/DB/Commands.pm
@@ -250,7 +250,7 @@ sub cmd_stepout {

     if( $sharp ) {
         my $frames;
-        1 while caller( 11 + $frames++ );
+        1 while caller( 12 + $frames++ );
         $frames_left =  $frames -$frames_left +1;

         return -2   if $frames_left <= 0; # Do nothing for unexisting frame
```

**But I do not know the option that will show output like this:**

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --left-right --cherry-mark --boundary --XX-OPTION 8cb6531...1295174
> 1295174 (HEAD -> reimplement) TEMPORARY
--- a/lib/file.pm
+++ b/lib/file.pm
@@ -250,7 +250,7 @@ sub zzzz {

 if( $code ) {
     my $frames;
-        code was
+        code now
     $var;

     return
> 0f477bf Prettify code
> 09630ef Setup $DB::single
= 3e4cc19 Debugger debugging is finished. Remove mark
= 3df5e8c Fix doc
> 1e1b4a3 Wrap whole DB::DB into &dbcall by moving DB::db into DB::interact
--- a/lib/DB/Commands.pm
+++ b/lib/DB/Commands.pm
@@ -250,7 +250,7 @@ sub cmd_stepout {

     if( $sharp ) {
         my $frames;
-        1 while caller( 11 + $frames++ );
+        1 while caller( 12 + $frames++ );
         $frames_left =  $frames -$frames_left +1;

         return -2   if $frames_left <= 0; # Do nothing for unexisting frame

o 6086d62 Code comment
```